# Delphi 10 Git how to commit to the Github?

Tags: git, github, delphi-10.3-rio

Using the Git integrated into Delphi 10.3 I can commit to a local repository but need help in committing to Github. I am able to do this from Visual Studio but not from Rad Studio. Please help!!

Comment: You never directly "commit to GitHub". Instead you commit locally and then push the changes to a remote. I don't know Delphi myself, but if it has a git client then I'm pretty usre you can also push to GitHub.

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Pushing_Your_Changes_to_the_Remote_Repository

Comment: Did you read Embarcadero's documentation yet? See [Git Integration in the IDE](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Git_Integration_in_the_IDE), there is a [Push command](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Pushing_Your_Changes_to_the_Remote_Repository) to "*push your changes to the remote repository*".

Comment: "the" remote repo. Seems like it doesn't handle multiple remotes.

Comment: I actually have read the git integration in the ide blurb. When I do the push, it tells me I have not set the url. My issue apparently is I don't know where to set the url.But, I do appreciate the help so thank you all.

Comment: How did you create your local repo. Did you clone from github?

Answer (score 1):

Initially, from Rad Studio, I was able to create my local repository and commit to it. But, if there is a way to make an initial push to github from Rad Studio, I haven't found it. [I have now. See below.] Every time I attempted the push I got the below screen. Notice the button says "Import".

What I saw when first I tried[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX2On.png)

My solution was to download github desktop. From there I created (another) repository and made a push with my project data.

Update* That screen spoofed me. I tried it again just now with a little tutorial project I had created earlier and discovered the button really should have said "Commit" because that is exactly what happened when I clicked on it; there was even a message box stating that was what happened.

After that I was able to push to github from Rad Studio.

In any case, I solved my issue.

Thank you for your help.